# How to save and display images served by REST API response bodies in Flutter?

Tags: android, rest, http, flutter, dart

I have a REST API that serves an image in its response body when a GET request is made to its URL. The sample response given on Postman is like:
[image: Postman response screenshot]
The headers in the response are as follows:

```
Date →Fri, 24 Apr 2020 17:32:51 GMT
Server →WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.9
Content-Type →image/jpeg
Vary →Accept, Cookie
Allow →GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options →DENY
Content-Length →161076
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
```

I tried to make a GET request to this API using flutter code and then print the content of the body in the response (just to see how the response body looks. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it) with the following code:

```
Future<void> getImage() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String filePath = "${directory.path}/loginCreds.txt";

    Map user_credentials = await this.getUserCreds(); //getUserCreds is another function in the same class
    String auth_token = user_credentials['auth_token'];

    Response res = await get(
      "http://10.0.2.2:8000/usermgmt/profile/picture/",
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Token $auth_token",
      },
    );
    print('\n\n\n Image Response body');
    print(res.body);
    print("\n\n\n");
  }
```

This gave the following output:

```
I/flutter (11120): 
I/flutter (11120): 
I/flutter (11120): 
I/flutter (11120):  Image Response body:
I/flutter (11120): ÿØÿà
I/flutter (11120): 
I/flutter (11120): 
I/flutter (11120):
```

How do I get the image from the response of the GET request, and set it as an image for a CircleAvatar within `build()` (using `setState()` within the function `getImage()` in the code snippet above) as well as save it in the file system?

Comment: try printing `res.statusCode`, `res.contentLength`, `res.headers`

Comment: @pskink Yes, I ran those print statements, the **status code is 200**, **contentLength is 161076**, and the headers are as follows: `{date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 08:29:36 GMT, vary: Accept, content-length: 161076, content-type: image/jpeg, x-frame-options: DENY, x-content-type-options: nosniff, server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.9, allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS}`

Comment: so you have binary image of type `image/jpeg` in `res.bodyBytes`

Comment: @pskink yes, I think so because `res.bodyBytes` is giving a list with numbers like `[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0,...`

Comment: so your problem is solved

Comment: @pskink How do I put the body bytes in a circular avatar?

Comment: use `MemoryImage`, but i am wondering why dont you use `NetworkImage` directly?

Comment: Thanks, @pskink the `MemoryImage` woked

Comment: I am not using `NetworkImage` directly because I don't know how to include the Auth Token in the header for the NetworkImage URL request

Comment: `const NetworkImage(
String url, {
double scale,
Map<String, String> headers
})` - it has `headers` parameter - the same as in `await get(...)`

Comment: `MemoryImage()` solved it for me too, `NetworkImage()` did not work for me as I was using `multipart` with `send.request()` to send a png file. Sending a png and retrieving a png from an API with flutter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, you are using the bad approach.

Flutter already have several methods to get an image by URL. For your `CircleAvatar`, you just have to do:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
    "http://10.0.2.2:8000/usr/profile/picture",
     headers: {
       "authorization": "Bearer $token",
       // Other headers if wanted
     },
  ),
)
```

Now download and save items on disk is another thing.

- For the easy solution, I can recommend you this plugin [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader)
- For the hardcoder solution (using the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package):

```dart
imageDownload(String url) async {
    Response response = await get(url);
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var parent = documentDirectory.path + "/images";
    var filePathAndName = "$parent/avatar.jpg"; // Build your image path here
    await Directory(parent).create(recursive: true); // Make sure directories exist
    File file2 = new File(filePathAndName);
    file2.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes); // Use bodyBytes instead
  }
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: it worked for image download. But, when it comes to CircleAvatar, I have to provide an Authorization token in the header of the request, not just the URL. So, how do I do that?

Comment: @SurajSJain I've edited the answer to reflect how to add headers to a NetworkImage request

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's happen with your API call but you should use the Image.network widget which is more simpler

```
Image.network('http://10.0.2.2:8000/usr/profile/picture')
```

Comment: it gives error of illegeal port used